# Unable To Activate The Wordpress Plugins : There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to Activate Any Plugin in my Wordpress Dashboard. After some time I got the error saying There is critical error on your site. After that i turned on debug as true in wp-config file. It showing

> "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I deactivated 3 plugins but after that i also unable to activate that 3 plugins too. 
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your server configuration, e.g. switch php version to higher level and mysql DB permission, etc.